# asp.net with strange URL

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, visual-studio-2017, .net-4.5

I developed an asp.net web application with VS 2017 and .net framework 4.5 but I don't know why the URL is appeared like the below attached image
IP Address/App Name/ (Some thing strange)/page name

[ASP.NET application URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/674tI.png)

Comment: Looks like a cookieless session ID.

Comment: Why it is appeared here, and how I can hide it?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479315.aspx, among others.

Comment: Thank you it is working now